# (Discord.py) I'm making a currency discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a currency discord bot, but I don't know how I should store the user id's and their info. (Money, owned items, etc) Does anyone know how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

you should use a Database e.g. mongodb or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a database like Postgres, Redis, Kafka. If it's a simple key-value pair like `userID: Cash` then Redis is the way to go due to its high speed and simplicity, if you want a relational database then go with Postgres as aforementioned (requires SQL knowledge) and speaking of which you can have a non-relational NoSQL database if that's your cup of tea.

Or maybe just go with a JSON file and call it a day (no, don't)